# Parameter missing error(rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am facing an error that when ever I try to call the function finalized_request it throws me an error saying "param is missing or the value is empty: finalizedeal". Since I am new to this I can't figure out what am I doing wrong(I am new to ROR).

Request_controller.rb

```
class RequestsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_request, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /requests
  # GET /requests.json
  def index
    @categories_list = Category.getAll()
  end
  def active
    user      = session[:user] 
    @requests = Array.new
    @tag = Array.new
    @requests = Request.getRequestByUser(user)
      @requests.each.with_index do |request, index|
      if request != nil
        @tag[index] = Array.new
        request[:tag_id].each do |t|
          @tag[index] << Tag.getTag(t)
        end
      end
    end
  end
  # GET /requests/1
  # GET /requests/1.json
  def show
    @user     = User.getUser(@request[:user_id])
    @tag = Array.new
    @request[:tag_id].each do |cate|
      @tag << Tag.getTag(cate)
    end
  end

  # GET /requests/1/edit
  def edit
    @tag = Array.new
    @request[:tag_id].each do |cate|
        @tag << Tag.getTag(cate)
    end
  end
  # POST /requests
  def post_request
    tags_arr         = params[:tags] ;
    #=begin
      #categories   = Array.new ;
      #if tags != nil
      #  tags.each do |tag|
      #    category  = Category.createCategoryIfNotExist(tag)
      #    if(category != nil)
      #      categories << category[:_id] 
      #    end
      #  end
      #end
    #=end
    tags   = Array.new ;
    if tags_arr != nil
      tags_arr.each do |t|
        tag  = Tag.createTagIfNotExist(t)
        if(tag != nil)
          tags << tag[:_id] 
        end
      end
    end
    request_data                = request_params
    user_id                     = session[:user] 
    request_data[:tag_id]  = tags 
    request_data[:user_id]      = user_id
    @request_                   = Request.createRequest(request_data)
    if @request_
      flash[:notice] = "Request Post successfully."
      redirect_to :action => "active"
    end


  end


  # PATCH/PUT /requests/1
  # PATCH/PUT /requests/1.json
  def update
    #tags         = params[:tags] ;
    #categories   = Array.new ;
    #if tags != nil
    #  tags.each do |tag|
    #    category  = Category.createCategoryIfNotExist(tag)
    #    if(category != nil)
    #      categories << category[:_id] 
    #    end
    #  end
    #end
    tags_arr         = params[:tags] ;
    tags   = Array.new ;
    if tags_arr != nil
      tags_arr.each do |t|
        tag  = Tag.createTagIfNotExist(t)
        if(tag != nil)
          tags << tag[:_id] 
        end
      end
    end
    Rails.logger.info("RequestsParams: #{request_params.inspect}")
    request_data                = request_params
    if request_data[:is_service] != "on"
       request_data[:is_service] = "off" 
    end
    user_id                     = session[:user] 
    request_data[:tag_id]  = tags 
    request_data[:user_id]      = user_id
    if Request.updateRequest(@request,request_data)
      flash[:notice] = "Request has been Edited successfully."
      redirect_to :action => "active"
    end
  end

  def delete_request ()
    if Request.delete_request(params[:id])
      flash[:notice] = "Request has been Deleted successfully."
      render :json => "great"
    end
  end

  # GET /requests
  def finalize_request()
    finalizedrequest = finalizedRequest_params
    request = Request.getRequest(finalizedrequest[:title])
    finalizedrequest[:title] = request[:title]
    Request.delete_request(request[:_id])
    FinalizedDeal.createFinalizedRequest(finalizedrequest)

    redirect_to :action => "bookmark"
  end 

  # GET /requests
  def bookmark
    user      = session[:user] 
    @requests = Array.new
    @tag = Array.new
    @requests = Request.getRequestByUser(user)
      @requests.each.with_index do |request, index|
      if request != nil
        @tag[index] = Array.new
        request[:tag_id].each do |t|
          @tag[index] << Tag.getTag(t)
        end
      end
    end
  end 



  # GET /requests
  def bookmark_request
    data = params[:d]
    bookmarked_against_Request = Request.getRequest(1)
    request_bookmarked = Request.getRequest(data)
    request_bookmarked_2 = request_bookmarked
    bookmarked_against_Request_2 = bookmarked_against_Request
    Rails.logger.info("Bookmark 2: #{bookmarked_against_Request_2.inspect}")
    #bookmarked_against_Request_2[:favourites] << request_bookmarked[:id]
    #request_bookmarked_2[:favourites_of] << bookmarked_against_Request[:id]
    #hello
    #Request.updateRequest(request_bookmarked , request_bookmarked_2)
    #Request.updateRequest(bookmarked_against_Request , bookmarked_against_Request_2)
    redirect_to :action => "bookmark"
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_request
      @request = Request.getRequest(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def request_params
      params.require(:request).permit(:title, :description, :type , :is_service , :required_user_location , :required_product_location ,:Upper_price_range , :lower_price_range , :negotiable , :type , :tags , :category_id)
    end

    def finalizedRequest_params
      params.require(:finalizedeal).permit(:title , :description)
    end
end
```

finalized_deal.rb

```
class FinalizeDeal
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :deal_details, type: String
  field :categories, type: Array
  field :owner_user, type: MongoId
  field :corsponing_user, type: MongoId

  field :title, type: String

  field :corresponding_product, type: String
  field :meeting_date, type: String
  field :date_finalized, type: String
  field :description, type: String

class << self
    def getRequestByUser(user_id)
      requests = where(user_id: user_id).to_a
      if requests
        requests
      end
    end

    def getFinzlizedRequest(req)
      request = find(req)
      if request
        request
      end
    end
    def createFinalizedRequest(req_data)
      request = self.new(req_data)
      if request.save
        request
      end
    end
    def updateFinalizedRequest(request,req_data)
      if request.update(req_data)
        request
      end
    end
    def delete_FinalizedRequest(req_id)
      if find(req_id).delete
        true
      end
    end
  end

end
```

request.html.erb

```
div id="form-details-modal-lbms" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
      <h3>Enter Contract Details:</h3>
      <!--<form>-->
      <%= form_tag({controller: "requests", action: "finalize_request"}, method: "GET",id:"post-form-lbms" ,data: {abide: ''}) %>
        <input type="hidden" id="currect_opened_req_id" value="" name="FinalizeDeal[title]"/>
        <select name="meeting-id">
          <option value="1">Meeting 1</option>
          <option value="2">Meeting 2</option>
        </select>
        <label for="details-lbms">Details</label>
        <textarea id="details-lbms" name="FinalizeDeal[description]"></textarea>
        <button class="button tiny">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
      <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
    </div>
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong. I am also posting a link to the screenshot of the error

http://tinypic.com/r/n6t8w2/8
http://tinypic.com/r/33kdq1k/8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is complaining because you are requiring the `:finalizedeal` parameter (but apparently you are not passing it along) by adding this `.require(:finalizedeal)` to this code:

```
def finalizedRequest_params
  params.require(:finalizedeal).permit(:title , :description)
end
```

So one solution would be to simply remove the `require` part. Like so:

```
params.permit(:title , :description)
```

[#require source](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-require)

> Ensures that a parameter is present.

Comment: Then why can't I get the value from finalizerequest_params in finalizedRequest. FinalizedRequest is null

Comment: You can't get the value from `finalizerequest_params` because that function is failing due to requiring a parameter than you are not passing to it. Subsequently, `finalizedrequest` is null because you do `finalizedrequest = finalizedRequest_params`.

Comment: I am sending the finalizedDeal. Have posted the form above

Comment: Your form confirms that I am right. You are sending ONLY `FinalizeDeal[description]` and `FinalizeDeal[title]`. You are never sending `FinalizeDeal[finalizedeal]` yet you are requiring the `:finalizedeal` param. Thus, you are missing a required parameter. Try what I suggest in my answer and see if it the error goes away.

Comment: You are requiring a parameter you haven't defined. Look in your finalized_deal.rb and you will find `:title`  and  `:description` but no `:finalize_deal`.  The model `FinalizeDeal` and the parameter `:finalize_deal` are not the same and the parameter doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just need to ask one more question. In the request_controller there is a function bookmark_Request in it I try to add data in the array 
`bookmarked_against_Request_2[:favourites] << request_bookmarked[:id]`
it always throws me an error saying 

**undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass** @DanCrews

Comment: Rails is telling you that request_bookmarked[:id] is nil and you can't push a nil value into the array. The first line in your method is missing the 'i' in 'id'.

Comment: Or, rather, you are trying to concatenate a value that doesn't exist because 'data' is nil.

Comment: If you're still having trouble @james it would be easier to resolve if you asked in a new question.